# Could not show the modal after if condition

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I have a problem regarding bootstrap modal: I have an input box and a button, in the input box, the user should type their code, then click the check button:

```
<form class="form-inline" action="" method="post">
  <div class="form-group">
    <input type="text" class="form-control input-sm input-inverse" name="appcode" required="" data-form-field="appcode" placeholder="Insert Your Code"></div>
  <div class="buttons-wrap">
    <button name="Xcheck" class="btn btn-secondary display-4 " type="submit" role="button" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#modalID">Check</button>
  </div>
</form>
```

When the button is clicked, it will run a PHP code in the same page, also check either the inserted code exists in the database or not.

Here is the php code:

```
<?php
  $con= mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "");
  mysqli_select_db($con, "cobathesis");

  if (isset($_POST['Xcheck'])){
    $appcode= $_POST['appcode'];
    $check=mysqli_query($con,"select * from applicantdata where appcode='$appcode'");
    $checkrows=mysqli_num_rows($check);

    if($checkrows>0) {
        // the modal should be loaded here
    }else{
        echo "<script>alert('You Inserted either the wrong Code or the Code is unregistered'); location.href='';</script>";
        }
  }
?>
```

Is it possible to use the same button (check button) to post the value and  load the modal at the same time?

Thank you for your response.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use something like

```
$('#myForm').on('submit', function(e){
  $('#myModal').modal('show');
  e.preventDefault();
});
```

[CodePen by Hana Piers](https://codepen.io/hanapiers/pen/EXNrGP)

Comment: should I put this inside the script tag in the end of the file?
because when I put this in the if condition, there will be an error appears

Comment: @PanjiPratama yes, that would be one solution. Of course you'd need to add an id to the form, and adjust the modal id to fit your modal's id.